# Mobilepress fails to translate short codes

Tags: plugins, customization, themes, mobile

I launched mobile version of my site some days ago. It was looking fine. I used `mobilepress` for the same. But i found that `shortcodes` are being displayed as simple text.

is there any other plugin to build efficient mobile version including short code translation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [WordPress Mobile Edition](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-mobile-edition/) or [WordPress Mobile Pack](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-mobile-pack/).